alternatives to import/include for importing library functions
I sometimes use xsl:import/xsl:include to import library functions, but its a bit clumsy. Things like saxon seem to import libraries by magic based on including a namespace in the root.
I probably have about 10 or so smallish (< 500 lines) files of XSLT code that I use, I'm just wondering if I'm doing this the sensible way?
I've tried xsl:include mostly to date.
I think I'd like to be able to take several xslt files that I current include and 'compile' them somehow into a single file/module/binary, that i can then refer to from the client code, and saxon to know where to get it from and what to do.

Do know XSLT 3 packages https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/using-xsl/compiling/packages.html? You can compile them https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html#compilePackage(java.io.File) and import them https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html#importPackage(net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltPackage). Might need more than HE to do that.

no I'll take a look

This is going to be processor-dependent, but since the various flavours of Saxon are about the only XSLT-3.0 game in town, I'll talk about SaxonJ.
The functions available to you basically come from three sources:

Functions written in XSLT within your stylesheet including its imported modules and used packages
Functions baked in to the Saxon processor (including extensions that we have chosen to bake in, such as the EXPath file and binary modules)
Extension functions either registered with the processor or loaded dynamically through reflection.

There's no mechanism to add functions written in XSLT via any Java API or configuration file, they can only be made available using the language features of xsl:include, xsl:import, and xsl:use-package.
